# Changing a Java mapping in a Graph

Tags: java, dictionary

I am trying to code a Graph in java and one of my member variables is a map that maps strings to integers. The integers are the indexes of a `List<List<Integer>>`. Lets say I have a graph like

```
"Alpha"   maps to 0, 
"Beta"    maps to 1, 
"Charlie" maps to 2, 
"Delta"   maps to 3.
```

If I delete `Beta` from my graph, I want to shift `Charlie` and `Delta` down. But, the Java map function can only get the values not the keys, so I can't change the mappings. How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Sounds like a map is not the correct data type for your problem.

Comment: Why don't you use `List<Vertex>` to represent the graph when you are trying to represent it as Adjacentry List? Where `Vertex` is a class represents a vertex in the graph. And `Vertex` has an attribute `List<Vertex> adjacentryList;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LinkedHashMap. There the insertion order of the keys are maintained.

If you want to maintain keys in an alphabetical order (or any other way), then use TreeMap. In this case, once you delete an entry, keys will sort themselves according to the rule (e.g. alphabetical order). The beauty of TreeMap is you can define the sorting rule here.

But, in any case HashMap is not a proper choice for you.

Comment: I am trying to sort it though based off of the values that the keys map to not based off of the keys themselves.

Comment: @nbro Not sure what you wanted to mean by this : " But, the Java map function can only get the values not the keys, so I can't change the mappings." If you are trying to sort based on the value that the keys map to, then TreeMap is the way : TreeMap(Comparator<? super K> comparator). Here you need to define a Comparator which basically compares the value the key points to.

Answer (score 0):

**Hashmap** is the best to link between two deferent objects see this [example](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=369)